# How to make a method in a jbutton?

Tags: java, swing, jbutton, actionlistener

So, i made a button like this
parameter nomor in `LoadPlanet` and `LoadRR` is parameter to show some data to textbox. 
my code is like this
the button appear correctly, but if i clicked the buttons, all of them show data from the last data which supposed to be data in last button.
-> a result from `tblplanet.JmlPlanet()` is 8, so the parameter was like LoadPlanet(8), so that every button show 8th data.

my question is how to make the parameter in sequence, so the button can show data correctly? Any ideas?

```
public void createButton() {
    for (i = 0; i < tblplanet.JmlPlanet(); i++) {
        tblplanet.draw(i + 1);
        planet_name = tblplanet.getNama_planet();

        JButton PlanetJButton = new JButton();
        PlanetJButton.setBounds(10, 5 + (i * 35), 95, 26);
        PlanetJButton.setText(planet_name);
        PanelButton.add(PlanetJButton);

        PlanetJButton.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener() {

                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
                        for (int i = 0; i < tblplanet.JmlPlanet(); i++) {
                            nomor =  i;

                            LoadPlanet(nomor);
                            LoadRR(nomor);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
}
```

Comment: It has nothing to do with JButtons... your actionPerformed method will load planet 0, then planet 1, then planet 2, then ... then planet 7

Comment: yeah logically i think it's true, but when i run that, it just show the last data, so i'm confused what i suppose to do

Answer (score 1):

Create a class which implements `ActionListener` and takes a parameter (`int`) of the planet that it represents

```
public class PlanetActionListener implements ActionListener {

    private final int planet;

    public PlanetActionListener(int planet) {
        this.planet = planet;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        LoadPlanet(planet);
        LoadRR(planet);
    }

}
```

Then simply add the `ActionListener` to your button

```
PlanetJButton.addActionListener(new PlanetActionListener(i));
```

Depending on how you code is structured, you may need to make the `PlanetActionListener` an inner class so it can access the appropriate methods. See [Nested Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html) for more details